# Fortrbbit app domain change

Tags: laravel, url, deployment, hosting, fortrabbit

So I am fairly new to laravel and especial to its deploying. I set up a fortrabbit application and got my website running so that's all good. The thing is though, the app url is not the one I wanted. I have an older website running without Laravel, and that is the url I want it to be hosted on. I have the ftp credentials for the old site but I have no clue how I can sort of clone the new Laravel site to the old one.

Briefly, I have a Laravel app running on insertname.eu1.frbit.net but I want it to be hosted on www.insertname.com which an older site is being hosted on for the time being.

Can anyone help me out? There must be a way to do this. Thanks alot!

Comment: Can't you just delete the old site files and upload the Laravel app in it's place? For a Laravel app to work you need to make sure you [configure the DocumentRoot](http://help.fortrabbit.com/domains#toc-set-a-custom-root-path) for that domain to point to the app's `public` directory.

Comment: You want to keep your fortrabbit application there or delete it?\

Comment: Well I don't mind. The thing is I thought the only way to get a laravel project online was through special laravel hostings like Fortrabbit. The only thing i want is to get it working on a url of choice, and not to be bound by the fortrabbit url.

Answer (score 1):

The fortrabbit "[App URL](http://help.fortrabbit.com/domains#toc-app-url)" is meant for testing/development/configuration and can't be changed. However you can [route other domains](http://help.fortrabbit.com/domains#toc-route-a-custom-domain) to your App on fortrabbit. You do so by pointing the domain to the "App URL" via a CNAME and by registering the domain in the App settings in the Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is indeed what I was looking for! I'll try it out immediately.